# JPA - InheritanceType.Joined generates wrong tables

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to represent in data base a editable table, with multiple field types.
My approach looks like this:

```
TABLES
- uuid //Primary key
- cols
- rows
- name  

VALUE
-col //Key element 
-row //Key element
-parent //Key element - table to witch the value belongs
-v_type //@DiscriminatorColumn

STRING_VALUE
-col //Key
-row //Key
-parent //Key
-value
```

This goes on for some more value types.

I've mapped it using eclipselink 2.3 as follows:

Table.java

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name="TABLES")
public class Table implements Serializable{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    long uuid;
    String name;
    int rows=0,cols=0;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Value.class,mappedBy="parent",cascade={CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
    @OrderBy("row ASC")
    List<Value> values;

}
```

Value.java

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@IdClass(ValueId.class)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="V_TYPE",length=1,discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Value implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT")
    Table parent;
    @Id @Column(unique=false)
    int row;
    @Id @Column(unique=false)
    int col;
}
```

ValueId.java

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ValueId implements Serializable{
    int row,col;
    long parent;
    // Getters setters etc
}
```

StringValue.java

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class StringValue extends Value {
    String value;
}
```

But with this implementation the resulting STRING_VALUE table
is lacking [parent] field. Thats bad because i can't resolve a value.

What have i done wrong ? ;)
I could not "google resolve" this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@Id` annotation on the `parent` field in `Value` should be replaced by [`@MapsId`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html).

But you would really do yourself a favor by having a technical, non-functional, auto-generated ID in `Value`, and let the `row`, `col` and `parent` field be regular fields of the entity. This wouldcertainly make things more performant, and much easier to use in all the parts of the application.

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking on it and I prefer your second solution.

Comment: +1 for the @mapsId and +100 for using simple ID instead of composite PK ;-)